# Unable to login more than one account of the same domain when using Azure AD as the IdP for G Suite

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, google-workspace

I'm using Google Cloud connector application to use our Azure AD account as a Single Sign-On with SAML SSO to access our GSuite Accounts. If I try to log in more than one user from our gsuite account, the page gets automatically gets redirected to the previously logged in account instead of asking me the password for the new account.

Consider two accounts A and B belonging to same domain XYZ. I'm not able to log in B as an additional account in Google service like Gmail if A is already logged in. After I enter the email B, if click on continue in the Google Sign-in page instead of taking me to the Microsoft SSO page, I directly get redirected to the mailbox of A. If I log out of account A and then try to login to account B, it's working fine. The behaviour gets replicated across browsers.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/2388498?key=4e3527ba1445fdd0c28fefebeca8ef6a

Please refer to the above video to watch the behaviour. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have google cloud account, my suggestion is just an idea. You can see if the URL redirect before you log in to your Microsoft account can be configured in goolge cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `&prompt=login` in `redirect url` or `Start URL`[in google](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

[Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)

[image]