# Azure AD callback URL is not getting hit every time

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js

It gets hit only when I clear site data and then try to login with Azure AD. Tried setting cache to no-store for all the requests but still not working.

Comment: Do you want to forcibly enter the user name and password for AD login every time you log in?

Comment: Can you please let me know what error is happening once the login is done? I understand it's not redirecting to the call back URL of your application, have you made sure you have configured the redirect_uri parameter correctly in the portal? If it's not hitting your app url, which URL is it ultimately navigating to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `prompt: 'login'`, like below in your nodejs project.

```
passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect',
{
    response: res,
    prompt: 'login',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true,
    successRedirect: '/'
}
)(req,res,next);
```

The specific implementation method is modified according to your project. Adding `prompt=login` in the redirect url can force a password to log in every time. It is no longer necessary to clean up the browser cache and log in with a username and password.

## Related Posts:

[1. Unable to login more than one account of the same domain when using Azure AD as the IdP for G Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746693/unable-to-login-more-than-one-account-of-the-same-domain-when-using-azure-ad-as)

[2. Providing user parameters in azure active directory authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749615/providing-user-parameters-in-azure-active-directory-authentication/65769829#65769829)